# Install gem https instead of git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, docker, rubygems

I have a `Gemfile` which contains a private repository

`gem 'private', git: 'git@github.com:user/private.git', branch: 'master'`

I want to install the dependency via https. To do this I do

```
ENV BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM="$GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic"
RUN git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
```

after which `bundle install` still requires login and password. What am I doing wrong?
I checked, the container has the correct token

```
/app # bundle install
Fetching git@github.com:user/private.git
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Comment: When using HTTPS it uses user and password authentication, you should use SSH so it will be easier for automation processes

Comment: If you have private gems, you better publish them to a private gem repo (like GitHub Packages or GemFury) and follow their straight forward instructions to install them. For example, see https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/configuring-rubygems-for-use-with-github-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem with `https` authorization, I had to throw `ssh` in the container.
I did so:
In the Dockerfile

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=ssh-key bundle install
```

building the image

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh ssh-key=./my-key -t ...
```